# Unable to increase the android emulator memory

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have created avd ram size with 768 which is limited as windows that it says while creating. And dataPartition.size=1000MB. This configuration doesn't let me install the apk file which is more than 30MB. It seems to be installed success. but When I tried to open It's not let me to open it. I just googled and found their will be some changes I need to do in config.ini  as per the commend I changed that file and increased the ram size to 1024MB But, still I faced the same issue which I faced earlier.

Comment: You mean default emulator? I suggest to use genymotion emulator because Android default emulator is too slow and creating issues when try to use with appium.

Comment: I would like to say yes. I used default emulator which comes along with android sdk. I will use genymotion which you suggested. Is it opensource, or commercial ? However let me google it. thank you so much.

Comment: You can download genymotion from here :https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download , it is free for personal use.

Comment: I tried to create the virtual device where I need to singin. I given valid credential which return user generic error message. The same I used to log in browser It let me to successfully logged in. Please do let me know what is the issue?

Comment: Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just done changes in config file which let me to change the memory allocation in emulator device. This issue has been addressed by myself.

Please delete the older .android folder which let you to create fresh avd devices.